# Windows Media Player - Display JPEG cover art for FLAC files

Tags: windows-7, flac

I got WMP 12 (on Windows 7 RC1) to play FLAC files by installing the [Ogg Vorbis/FLAC, Direct Show filters](http://www.xiph.org/dshow/), but WMP does not display the embedded cover artwork.

After experimenting I found that it will display the cover art if it is embedded in PNG format, but up to now I've used JPEG for all my FLAC files.

Rather than re-tagging all my files, does anyone know a way to get WMP 12 to display JPEG embedded cover art?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [WMP Tag Plus plugin](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/index.htm?http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmptagplus/).

> WMP Tag Plus is a free Windows Media Player plug-in that adds support for reading and writing tags (metadata) of additional music formats like FLAC, Ogg Vorbis and WavPack.

I downloaded the program and now I can see the cover art and can modify the files.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but a friend of mine made a [solution for playing FLAC in WMP](http://castlemadeofsand.wordpress.com/) which adds supports for tags and apparently works better with seeking. I don't know if it works with album art, if it doesn't then let me know and I'll bug him to add it. Sorry for the fluffy response but I don't have WMP to hand to test.

Comment: Whoops. Had forgotten about this question... Just tried 'FLAC Property Handler' but doesn't support album art (yet?). Thanks though.

Comment: Just checked with the author, he doesn't have time to work on it currently but if he did, album art is next on his list!